# iPhone: UITableview seperator disappars when the list is long?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a grouped tableview which I set its background like this in viewDidload;

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.separatorColor= [UIColor APP_SEPERATOR_COLOR];
```

and this is method I set:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];            
    }
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundView.alpha=0;
        cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;

    return cell;
```

This works ok but when there are 30-40 cells then the separation line and borders of table starts to get lost when I scroll down, and never comeback again..when I scroll up.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just setting the seperatorColor in the nib instead of in code?

Comment: @MSgambel no but I want to be able to set it in code

Comment: Why may I ask? You should see if it is working in the nib, and if it is, it may have something to do with your code.

Comment: What is APP_SEPERATOR_COLOR? is it the custom color ?

Comment: @Control-V yes I updated the code plslook

Comment: @David Schiefer I tried your aproach but didnt help, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the cells get reused when they scroll on and off the screen. In this case the customization in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called. This will override what is already drawn, including the border.

Simply move your code styling the cell into the cell definition part:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];            
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView.alpha=0;
}
    cell.textLabel.text=cellValue;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont APP_QUESTIONS_FONT];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor APP_TEXT_COLOR];
return cell;
```

Comment: tnx for reply, I tried the code above, now lines does not disappear but I see lots of misplaced horizontal lines without rounded rectangle and borders

Comment: That sounds like you have your `UITableViewStyle` set to `UITableViewStyleGrouped`. Check that first. -- Also, make sure you got the edit above from `..SingelLine` to `..None`.

Comment: but I want it to be grouped style

Comment: Aah, this is new information. In this case you have to distinguish between the cells that are at the end of a section and those that are not. The cells at the end of a section don't get the separator. Also, you might have to tweak the width of the `UIView` to accommodate the different shape of the grouped style cells.

Comment: Tnx, I say "grouped view" in question, the thing is why do I need to tweak and hack around the code to see the tableview borders in a long list? everything is standart here, cells are standart too, only when I set background of cell to transparent then borders of table get lost at the -bottom half of- the page. everything else is in pretty standart settings. please have a look at the question

Answer (score -2):

> Why can not you say

```
self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.56f  saturation:0.98 brightness:0.65 alpha:0.6];
```

> there itself? because when you scroll the UITableView each cell call APP_SEPERATOR_COLOR and then takes time to re-drawn. is there any reason to use APP_SEPERATOR_COLOR as a separate method ?

Comment: cause I want all colors to be in one place, so I can change them easily from one class. problem is not slowness, they totally get disappear

Comment: Wait. WHAT? Please delete this answer, its nonsense.

Comment: As Joost says, this is wrong.  The method APP_SEPERATOR_COLOR (which I assume to be a define or a category method) on UIColor will only be called once at the initial assignment of the separator color.  That method returns an autorelease UIColor instance, which is assigned to the separatorColor property.  That instance is then checked on redraw of the table.  It has no impact on performance.